# How to combine 3 tuples together in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I tried to count the character combine in the list.  In my script, I can count the tuples, but I don't know how I can count the total of characters in my list.

This is the script I have used.

```
def count(num):
    character = 0
    for i in num:
        character += 1
    return character

count ('1234','1234',1234')
```

my answer is 3

I want to show 12.  How can I do that?

Comment: `character += len(i)`?

Comment: Also, I doubt that your code _actually_ gives you an answer of 3 ... It looks more like it would give you a `TypeError` since you're calling `count` with 3 arguments and it only takes 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def count(num):
    total = 0
    for i in num:
        total += len(i)
    return total
```

Or, shorter and more pythonic:

```
def count(num):
    return sum(len(x) for x in num)
```

Also you'll need to call it with a list or tuple argument, e.g. count (('1234','1234','1234'))

You also could add a star to the method definition (def count(*num)) to make it able to be called the same way you did originally.

Answer (score 3):

I'd prefer James' method since it feels more idiomatic, but this is what a functional approach would look like:

```
def count(num):
    return sum(map(len, num))
```

If you want this to work by calling `count('1234', '1234', '1234')` instead of `count(('1234', '1234', '1234'))`, you can define the function with `def count(*num)`.

Finally, if you want both of those calls to work (and you're sure the atomic type is only ever a string), you can do this:

```
def count(*num):
    return sum(len(n) if isinstance(n, str) else count(*n) for n in num)
```

Comment: This method is faster as well, it's definitely a good way of doing it. I think mine is more readable, in general, but if I was actually doing this on large data sets I would definitely go with this method.

Comment: @James Are you sure about this being faster? I thought generator comprehensions were pretty well optimized.

Comment: [Slightly, yeah](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map). They are pretty well optimized, the sort of difference map would make would only very rarely be useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are needing the function for various operations you could use the following definition (as long as mylist is not a nested list).

```
def countchars(mylist):
    return sum([len(item) for item in mylist])
```

Alternatively, you could merge the tuples/lists together and use len() to get the length of the merged tuple/list.

Comment: This has the downside that it needs to first make a new list. Better use a generator comprehension.

Comment: It also has the downside that it doesn't return the result after calculating it ;)

Comment: Is fixed, those Typos...